# c# Linq to find children

Tags: c#

I have a class below and i want to check to see if the student have  enrolled in a certain course.

```
public class Student
{ 
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

}

public class Enrollment
{
    [Required]
    public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment i have this query from to my database.

```
          var student=  await _context
         .Student
         .Include(c => c.Enrollments)
         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == StudentId);
```

Can anyone tell me a nice way of checking that the student has not registered already for the course if i have the courseId in the enrollments object.

Comment: you can add a property in the enrollment object like an `enum` indication if the `Student` is registered or not or you can do a further `Include` by using `ThenInclude` in your query and fetch the `Course` class  and do a check on a property in the `Course`. i hope i understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from a single student:

```
  var student=  await _context
     .Student
     .Include(c => c.Enrollments)
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == StudentId);
  return student.Enrollments.Any(x => x.CourdeId == aCourseId); //returns true if such an erloment exists
```

Queriyng students that not are registered for a course

```
  var students =  await _context
     .Student
     .Include(c => c.Enrollments)
     .Where(s => !s.Enrolments.Any(x => x.CourseId == aCourseId));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  var student=  await _context
     .Student
     .Include(c => c.Enrollments)
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == StudentId);

return student.Enrollments.Any(c => c.CourseId == cId && c.RegisterState == RegisterState.Registered)
```

`RegisterState` is an enum with two states that you update on registration.